# How to run ssh command until succeeded?

Tags: ssh, scripting, watch

Sometimes I restart a device and need to `ssh` back in when it's ready.

I want to run the ssh command every 5 seconds until the command succeeds.

My first attempt:

```
watch -n5 ssh me@device.local && exit 1
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you want an interactive SSH session?

Comment: @Nobody yes I do

Comment: Ok, I first thought my idea wouldn't work interactively, but a short test showed that it does so I wrote an answer anyway. :)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Another option would be to use `until`.

```sh
until ssh me@device.local; do
    sleep 5
done
```

---

If you do this repeatedly for a number of hosts, put it in a function in your `~/.bashrc`.

```sh
repeat()
{
read -p "Enter the hostname or IP of your server :" servername
until ssh $servername; do
    sleep 5
done
}
```

Comment: thanks, I'm going to use the repeat script but with `$` instead of the prompt :-)

Comment: It is worth noting that `ssh` can exit with a non-zero status after having connected successfully if something external to the connection terminates the session, in which case that script will attempt to reconnect.  This may or may not be a desirable side effect.

Answer (score 44):

```sh
ssh me@device.local
until !!; do sleep 5 ; done
```

The `!!` to repeat the last command.

Answer (score 35):

OpenSSH has a `ConnectionAttempts` setting that does almost what you want. The default is 1 but you can change it in `ssh_config` or on the command-line:

```sh
ssh -o 'ConnectionAttempts 10' ...
```

Unfortunately you can't adjust the attempt interval which is fixed at 1 second, but you can adjust the connection attempt time-out `ConnectTimeout` (in seconds) in the same fashion.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working for me :/

Comment: @Freedo: Could you please explain what exactly you tried and what exactly didn't work? Also, it would likely be better to [write a new question](/questions/ask) about your issue. You're welcome to draw my attention to it through a a link in the comments.

Comment: If it wasn't for the spurious (in my opinion) 5 second interval, this would be the correct answer. It certainly gets my upvote.  A suggested addition to make the thing even more convenient, put this ...
    alias YH="ssh -o 'ConnectionAttempts 20' you@yourhost"
... in your ${HOME}/.profile.  Then, after reboot, you'd just have to type YH on the command line, pour another coffee, take a sip ... and you're in.

Comment: created bash fn `sshr() { ssh $1 -o "ConnectionAttempts 10" }` so I can do this `sshr destination`

Comment: @JohnLee Better would be `sshr() { ssh -o "ConnectionAttempts 10" $@ }` so you can pass multiple arguments.

Answer (score 15):

```sh
while ! ssh user@host.example.com true; do
    sleep 5
done; echo "Host is back up at $(date)!"
```

Comment: Or, if you don't want to actually log in until the service is up, `while ! nc -w5 -z host.example.com 22; do [...]`.

Answer (score 5):

`autossh` keeps ssh sessions alive. With the right parameters you can also launch it when it's currently impossible to connect and it will try until it succeeds. This works fine, but if you want the *re*connect part to work nicely with interactive sessions you'll need to combine it with `screen` or equivalent.

I recommend this:

```
AUTOSSH_POLL=5 AUTOSSH_GATETIME=0 autossh -M 0 -o ServerAliveInterval=5 -o ServerAliveCountMax=1 user@host
```

But see its man page for details. With the above parameters, `autossh` will try launching ssh every `AUTOSSH_POLL` seconds, `AUTOSSH_GATETIME=0` makes it try again if the first try fails (so definitely what you want), `-M 0` disables connection checking by autossh, all later options are passed to ssh. The two `-o` options make ssh exit if the connections drops for more than 5s.

Answer (score 2):

At the risk of just throwing code at an answer, this script works for me on a daily basis. I call it `ressh` and it can be used as simply as `ressh {hostname}`, or with care, `ressh -S {session_name} {hostname}`

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Repeatedly attempt to reconnect to a remote ssh server
########################################################################
#
prefix="${0/*\/}"
port=
session=
action=ssh              # How to connect remotely

while getopts 'l:Lp:P:S:' OPT
do
    case "$OPT" in
        l)      [[ s == "$OPTARG" ]] && action=list ;;
        L)      action=list ;;
        [Pp])   port="$OPTARG" ;;
        S)      session="$OPTARG";; ## ; [[ $session =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] && session="${prefix}-$session" ;;
    esac
done
shift $(($OPTIND - 1))

host="$1"
shift

if [[ -z "$host" ]]
then
    echo "ERROR: Missing hostname" >&2
    exit 1
fi


if [[ list == "$action" ]]
then
    ssh ${port:+-p $port} "$host" "screen -ls"
    exit 0
fi

# Connect repeatedly to the target host system
#
[[ -z "$session" ]] && session="${prefix}-$$.$host"

while :
do
    ssh -tt ${port:+-p $port} "$host" "screen -dr $session || screen -S $session $*"
    ss=$?
    [[ 0 -eq $ss ]] && break

    [[ 255 -eq $ss ]] && sleep 4
    sleep 1
    echo "Reconnecting to session $session on $host..."
done


# All done
#
exit 0
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it within a command for [Shuttle App for Mac](https://fitztrev.github.io/shuttle/). Similar to [David's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/404889/307356). This command connects to and reboots the server and then tries to reconnect to it again until it succeeds.

```
{
  "name": "Server - REBOOT",
  "cmd": "ssh -t root@XXX.XXX.XX.XX 'reboot -p' ; sleep 1 ; echo 'Reconnecting. Standby...' ; sleep 2 ; ssh -o 'ConnectionAttempts 10' root@XXX.XXX.XX.XX"
},
```