# Tool to run a command until exit status is 0

Tags: process, exit-status

Is there a tool that can accept a command and run it over and over until exit status is 0?

I could probably check for value of $? in a loop but I wonder if there's a standard program for this

Comment: [How to run ssh command until succeeded](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/404792/how-to-run-ssh-command-until-succeeded)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, I think the loop is so trivial it hasn't been encoded into a command. Something like

```
while !cmd; do sleep 1; done
```

Comment: Or `until cmd; do :; done` to use `until` and without the delay.